# Sort in bash - how to sort by characters lying middle or end of line

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have the following pdf files to be combined.

```
20121024aC004101
20121024a_002101
20121024a_003101
20121024aN006101
20121024aA001101
20121024a_005101
etc...
```

But my result should be in the order of 00101, 002101... i.e. sort based on 11th charater;
anybody can help me. I am new to bash, recently started to learn.

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
sort -k1.11
```

The `-k` switch tells `sort` to sort on the first field from the 11th character.